# Is there a way to automatically create Azure Dev Ops test cases from a test assembly or from a solution with test scripts?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, automated-tests

Is there a way to automatically create Azure Dev Ops test cases from a test assembly or from a solution with test scripts?  With TFS 2015, I know that you can [automatically create cases using the tcm.exe command line tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/dd465191(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).  But we are migrating to Azure Dev Ops, and we need to migrate our test plans and test cases as well.  As of now, we are told that we'll need to manually associate the test scripts with test cases one-by-one.  Is there a way to replicate tcm.exe's /import functionality with Azure Dev Ops?

Comment: Are you upgrading to Azure DevOps or migrating from another tool?

Comment: You don't necessarily have to have a test case item created to execute the tests.  You can run targeting an assembly (including wildcards) and it will do the test case discovery.  Believe it will also manage the test point history.  Use the "Test Assembly" option for test selection.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops#arguments

Comment: We are upgrading from TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps Server.  (I think that counts as 'upgrade' rather than 'migrate')

Running tests via Assembly is interesting.  I will investigate that.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Matt. TCM.exe primary use case was to associate test automation to Test case work items so that they could be executed as part of the automated workflow.

However, with the new Pipelines capabilities, you no longer require the test automation to be associated with Test Case workitems. You can run the test automation directly within Pipelines.

See for more info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops#arguments

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/parallel-testing-vstest?view=azure-devops

Comment: Interesting.  I will investigate & accept if this works for us.

Comment: @Ken Is running tests via Assembly working for you?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  We are too invested in Test Cases / Test Suites.  We have tests for multiple teams that share a single assembly, and we also want the reporting associated with test cases.

Comment: I've noticed you upgraded from TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps Server, so you can install VS 2017 to use tcm.exe. VS 2019 has removed tcm.exe.

Comment: Unfortunately, I won't have access to the new platform for a few weeks. I will test TCM and post here when I get the chance.